# Histplot : legend disappears when location is set, instead a small square appears in the specified location

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

Random DataFrame just to show my issue :

```
numbers = pd.Series(np.random.choice(10,50), name='numbers')
colors=pd.Series(np.random.choice(['A','B'],50), name='colors')
df = pd.concat([numbers, colors], axis=1)
```

I'm plotting a histogram using Seaborn, legend displays just fine by default :

```
sns.histplot(data=df, x='numbers', hue='colors')
plt.show()
```

[image: legend displays fine]

When trying to move my legend using loc, I get an empty square in the desired location instead :

```
sns.histplot(data=df, x='numbers', hue='colors')
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

[image: empty square instead of legend]

How can I move my legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

```
numbers = pd.Series(np.random.choice(10,50), name='numbers')
colors=pd.Series(np.random.choice(['A','B'],50), name='colors')
df = pd.concat([numbers, colors], axis=1)

ax = sns.histplot(data=df, x='numbers', hue='colors') #<========== returning ax
sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left") <============== calling the move_legend method
```

Output:

[image]

Further reading:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html